# Elasticsearch illegal_argument_exception when indexing date_nanos field value

Tags: date, elasticsearch

I'm attempting to index OpenTelemetry data that uses nanosecond epochs for span timings. I have the following contained in my index mappings (verified via `GET /index/_mappings`:

```
"startTimeUnixNano": {
    "type": "date_nanos"
},
```

But when indexing a document with this value:

```
"startTimeUnixNano":1700860667233615872,
```

Elasticsearch throws an `illegal_argument_exception`:

```
{
    "error":{
        "root_cause":[
            {
                "type":"document_parsing_exception",
                "reason":"[1:1723] failed to parse field [resourceSpans.scopeSpans.spans.startTimeUnixNano] of type [date_nanos] in document with id 'OMxXDowB4M_uH230iKzE'. Preview of field's value: '1700860667233615872'"
            }
        ],
        "type":"document_parsing_exception",
        "reason":"[1:1723] failed to parse field [resourceSpans.scopeSpans.spans.startTimeUnixNano] of type [date_nanos] in document with id 'OMxXDowB4M_uH230iKzE'. Preview of field's value: '1700860667233615872'",
        "caused_by":{
            "type":"illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason":"date[+53900098-12-02T05:46:55.872Z] is after 2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807 and cannot be stored in nanosecond resolution"
        }
    },
    "status":400
}
```

It's obviously accepting this huge timestamp value in a format with less precision than nanoseconds, since the date evaluated by Elasticsearch is so far into the future, but I've set the index mappings to `date_nano` so I don't know why I can't give it a nanosecond epoch.

I've confirmed the provided nanosecond timestamp is within range via (JavaScript):

```
new Date(1700860667233615872 / 1000000)
```

which gives Nov 24, 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to divide the value you send to ES by 1000000 like you did in your JS code, i.e. sending this will work and will have the correct resolution

```
"startTimeUnixNano": 1700860667233.615872,
```

This will resolve to

```
Friday, November 24, 2023 9:17:47.233615
```

Comment: Thank you. I would have thought with a nanosecond precision timestamp I could send an integer value.